# Locuzione "mi piace da matti"

Tags: idioms

Ho letto la frase "[cosa] mi piace da matti". È probabilmente una espressione per dire "mi piace moltissimo".

Ma non capisco perché "matti" è al plurale. È soltanto idiomatico o c'è una ragione? qui, "matti" è sostantivo o aggettivo? Ci sono altre espressioni come questa?

Comment: Vedi anche la voce [“da”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/da/) del Treccani, verso la fine del punto 3, dove parla di “espressioni modali, ellittiche” come “far vita da cani (= come i cani), menar bòtte da orbi” etc.

Comment: @DaG grazie, non ho visto questa parte. "Verbo _da_ X" ~ "verbo _come_ X". Adesso ha più senso.

Answer (score 2):

Dalla [definizione di Treccani per matto](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/matto1/), puoi trovare una sacco di modi di dire e frasi idiomatiche.

> roba da matti, cose da matti, incredibili, assurde;

ma anche

> Gridare da matto

Ci sono anche casi in cui si può declinare sia al singolare che al plurale:

> Andare matto/i per la cioccolata

Lo stesso discorso si può fare, ad esempio, per un sinonimo di matto, cioè pazzo.

In altri casi si può dire:

> Questo genere di film è roba da intenditori  
> Questo pista è da roba da
>   esperti o da sciatore esperto

Comment: Grazie, nel Treccani c'è:

"e come locuz. avv., per significare impeto, violenza: gridare da matto, correre da matti"

= "locuzione avverbiale". Perché _gridare da matto_ e non _gridare da matti_? o _correre da matto_? sono possibili entrambi?

Comment: @JanBerkel Per correre si dice più frequentemente _correre come un matto_. Esempio al singolare: "Ho corso come un matto tutta la mattina per fare gli acquisti di Natale"; oppure al plurale: "Abbiamo corso come matti tutta la mattina per fare gli acquisti di Natale".

Comment: In realtà credo che _roba da matto_ sia altrettanto valido di _roba da matti_, solo che quest'ultima è più usata.  Così come si può usare anche _gridare da matti_ (io l'ho sentito di più che non al singolare). Si può anche dire _roba da intenditore_. In definitiva, credo siano forme consolidate dall'abitudine, ma senza una regola fissa. Infine, credo che  queste locuzioni si originino spesso come  forme abbreviate; es.:
_gridare da matti_ = _gridare come fanno i matti_ e _roba da intenditori_ = _roba da lasciare agli intenditori_

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi ho fatto una richiesta con [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*_VERB+da+matti%2C+*_VERB+da+matto&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A_VERB%20da%20matti%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Broba_VERB%20da%20matti%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A8_VERB%20da%20matti%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpiace_VERB%20da%20matti%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpiaceva_VERB%20da%20matti%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdiverte_VERB%20da%20matti%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdivertiva_VERB%20da%20matti%3B%2Cc0). non ho trovato una frase di tipo "[verbo] da matto", è sempre "da matti".

Comment: @Jan Berkel "Si comporta da matto" è corretta IMO